# vue two array loop in one ul

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can I loop two array in one ul? for example something like this `v-for="frag1 in fragM; frag2 in fragP` this code obviously doesn't work

```js
data:{
 damage:null,
 fragP:[],
 fragM:[]
},
methods{
 suuu(){
  //damage is any number
  this.fragP.push(this.damage)
  //damage is any number but different
  this.fragM.push(this.damage)
 }
}
```

```html
<ul v-for="frag2 in fragM" v-for="frag1 in fragP"> <!––thoes two loops not working but i want something like this––>
 <li style="background:green">{{frag1}}</li>
 <li style="background:red;">{{frag2}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `computed property`:

```
computed: {
   something: function () {
      return this.fragM.concat(this.fragP);
    }
}
```

And use it in template:

```
<ul v-for="frag in something"...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the two arrays will always be the same size (or one will reliably be smaller), use indexes. For example:

```
<ul v-for="(frag, index) in fragM" :key="index"> 
// (keep in mind that this creates a ul for every set of 2, probably not desired)
    <li>{{ fragM[index] }}</li>
    <li>{{ fragP[index] }}</li>
</ul>
```

Once you get that working nicely, convert it to a method that sanity checks your array size and avoids undefined results.